# How to allow user to scroll up with css snap?

Tags: css, scroll, scroll-snap

I have a chatbox that can contain a lot of messages. Each time a new message is sent, the div scrolls up to the bottom thanks to css snap property.

However, if I want to scroll up, the div will automatically go back to bottom. How to allow a persisting scroll up, and go back to bottom only if a new message is added to the list?

Here is a code idea:

```css
.container{
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
}

textarea{
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>message 1</div>
   <div>message 2</div>
   <div>message 3</div>
   <div>message 4</div>
   <div>message 5</div>
   <div>message 6</div>
   <div>message 7</div>
   <div>message 8</div>
   <div>message 9</div>
   <div>message 10</div>
  <textarea placeholder="write message"></textarea>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove:

```
textarea{
scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

And add the 'snap-code' to the event that submits the text.